# How to reclass in Google Earth Engine with 'and' or 'or' statement

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do you reclassify in with an 'and' or 'or' statement? This piece of code is not working.

```
var reclass13 = ee.Image(1).where(y13.gte(mG13h),1000)
                        .where(y13.lt(mG13l),100)
                        .where(y13.lt(mG13h).and(y13.gte(mG13l),1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have misplaced the replacement value for the third `where`, so that it's being passed to the `and` instead: try changing

```
.where(y13.lt(mG13h).and(y13.gte(mG13l),1));
```

to this:

```
.where(y13.lt(mG13h).and(y13.gte(mG13l)), 1);
```

If that doesn't help, please edit your question to provide a complete example script that we can run and also show what error or incorrect result you're getting.